# Passing javascript variable to thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I'm working on a Spring MVC project and what I need now is to generate a table with a number of rows that is specified by the user from an input and doing that without refreshing the page.

Here is my HTML file

```
..............

                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="numberRow1" placeholder="number">
                  <button type="button" id="execute1">Execute</button>

                  <div th:text="${myvar}" class="test"></div>

                            <div id="table1" class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-bordered">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th scope="col">Column Name</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Type</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Index</th>
                                            <th scope="col">AI</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                                            <td><select id="inputState" class="form-control">
                                                    <option selected>Choose...</option>
                                                    <option>INT</option>
                                                    <option>VARCHAR</option>
                                                    <option>DATE</option>
                                            </select></td>
                                            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                                            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
.....................
```

And The script I'm trying to working with

```
    <script th:inline="javascript">
        /*<![CDATA[*/
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#execute1").click(function() {
                var getVal = $("#numberColumn1").val();
                $(".test").html(getVal);
                var myvar = /*[[${myvar}]]*/ getVal;;
            });
        })
        /*]]>*/
    </script>
```

At this point I'm just trying to get the value of **"myvar"** and show it in this section `<div th:text="${myvar}" class="test"></div>`

But nothing works for me so far ..

Any help please because I really need it.
TY.

Comment: Thymeleaf is server side processed.  If you don't want to refresh the page, then you can't really use Thymeleaf for this.

Comment: I thinks there is a way using javascript or ajax to do that